# How to ensure a tamperproof/tamperevident boot disk on google compute engine?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

On gce you can add a second disk and mark it as read only. It looks like this is not possible with the boot disk. I'm not sure if this is related to some cloud init thing. At least when you ssh from within the browser then keys are copied to the VM. But to some extend this could be solved with overlayfs. The keys are deleted after some minutes automatically anyways. Are there other files which need to be writable all the time from googles side? So not just after the first setup?
I need to create a machine which is immutable most of the time, and I just tick some option when I want to have it read write.

There are shielded VMs but they only check the boot sequence and nothing afterwards. There are also some other linux options like IMA which require a  TPM and could be used to ensure the machine boots into a known state. Can you add a TPM to a standard, i.e. non shielded gce instance?

Comment: Once the VM starts its boot process, security is your responsibility. To accomplish your goals, you will need to install third-party software and setup external resources to monitor your instances. You will also need to create exception lists as the OS does make changes to the system while running. An operating system with applications is not static. Here is one example of a third-party tool: https://linux-audit.com/monitoring-linux-file-access-changes-and-modifications/ This area is very broad with many details to conder and many vendors in this space.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question Google does update more files than SSH keys such as /etc/resolv.conf around every 24 hours or so.

On the subject for TPM on GCP some images such as Debian 9 have TPM support on which you might configure your own module (anything installed inside your machine is outside the scope of support for GCP).

There is a known regresion with Debian 10 image from GCP (maintained by Debian) where TPM is no longer supported but a [thread](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/merge_requests/191) has been started to enable it again

Comment: Is changing some configs like resolv.conf really required after the first setup? In the end you can use your own ssh keys and change the nameserver to something else. For the TPM: what does support mean? Support from debian or from google? Sure you need some software to interact with the TPM, this would be a Debian issue. But at first you need a TPM after all. Is there some option to attach a vTPM to a gce instance? Shielded VM's do that automatically but I don't know if this is possible for a standard VM.

Comment: Compute Engine instances are configured to renew DHCP leases every 24 hours. For instances that are enabled for zonal DNS, the DHCP lease expires every hour. DHCP renewal overwrites this file, undoing any changes that you might have made https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns . To clarify the support topic it means that the OS allows you to use TPM but if you need any help with the configuration GCP may only help as a best effort because anything running inside your instance is outside of their scope.